# sed search and replace with variable containing slash

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

I am trying to replace a string inside a text file with a variable.

I am using this code:

```
sed -i "s/search text \/TAG\//replace text ${variable}/" ${textfile}
```

The content of the variable is `/newTAG/`. And the content of the variable is the problem, more accuratelyte the `/` at the beginning and the end.

When both `/` are removed so the content is only `newTAG` everything works fine.

I already tried the following

```
sed -i "s/search text \/TAG\//replace text "${variable}"/" ${textfile}
sed -i 's/search text \/TAG\//replace text "${variable}"/' ${textfile}
```

Can anybody help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use something other than `/` as the delimiter for the regex (for example, the colon `:`):

```
sed -i "s:search text /TAG/:replace text ${variable}:" "${textfile}"
```

Or escape the `/` in the variable.